# Que signifie "toque" ici ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* I, dans sa cellule au Danemark, le narrateur fait une réflexion sur la monarchie :

> Avant l’ère des Libérations un prince vous sortait de cellule d’un mot
> ! un Noël ! Maintenant ! allez voir ! Ah la situation est **toque** ! Le
> roi Oluf, là d’où je me ronge, il pourrait pas me sortir d’un mot ! Il
> se ferait fesser par la foule si il lui venait la moindre fredaine.

J'ai regardé le mot *toque* dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toque) et dans le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toque/78472), tout de même, je ne comprends pas très bien le sens de la phrase.

À votre avis, s'agit-il d'une métonymie du pouvoir républicain (TLF : *Toque de juge; porter la robe et la toque; en toque et en robe*) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Toque* est ici un adjectif. On ne trouve pas cet emploi du mot écrit tel quel dans les dictionnaires de langue usuels. Voici ce que j'ai trouvé dans le *Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel* :

> **Toquard, Toque**, (voir **tocard, toc**)

Ce serait donc une autre orthographe de *toquard*, ce qui parait plausible d'après le contexte.

Le *Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel*<sup>1</sup> mentionne à *toquard* les sens qu'on trouve dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tocard) et en donne un autre qui me semble mieux convenir dans le contexte :

> ridicule, lamentable.

Ferdinand exprime sa nostalgie de la monarchie en se lamentant sur la situation dans laquelle il se trouve : le roi ne pourrait pas le sortir de là même s'il le voulait.
Ferdinand *se lamente* parce que la situation est *lamentable*.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey. Hachette.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Peut être à rapprocher de l'expression "être toqué". Mais j'ai jamais entendu ou lu une utilisation pareille.

La situation est toquée => un peu folle.

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toqu%C3%A9/78473

Comment: La question porte sur « toque », pas « toqué ».